# How to join html elements like with Array.join()

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My map function:

```
const artists = this.props.result.artists.map((artist) => {
        return <Link value={artist.name} className='artist-title'>{artist.name}</Link>
    });
```

When displayed with:

```
artists.join(', ');
```

Results in: [object Object], [object Object]

When simply displayed with:

```
artists
```

Results in: EminemNate Dogg

My goal is: Eminem, Nate Dogg

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: the question isnt how, the question should why

Comment: These are not HTML elements. This is jsx. They are all objects. What is the expected output?

Comment: Are you sure you have array of string in `artists`?